# C# Update Network Adapter Name partially working (WinReg good, ipconfig bad)

Tags: c#, windows, networking, registry, adapter

Given the following function:

```
private void UpdateNetworkAdapterName(string pnpDevID, string oldAdpterName, string newAdapterName)
    {
        string guid = "";

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
        {
            if (string.Equals(m["PNPDeviceID"].ToString(), pnpDevID))
            {
                guid = m["GUID"].ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Environment.MachineName, RegistryView.Registry64);
        regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Network\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\\" + guid + "\\Connection", true);
        regKey.SetValue("Name", newAdapterName);

        bool successful = false;
        foreach (NetworkInterface netAd in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (netAd.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
            {
                if (string.Equals(netAd.Name, newAdapterName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Successfully updated network adapter from {oldAdpterName} to {newAdapterName}");
                    successful = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!successful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to updated network adapter from {oldAdpterName} to {newAdapterName}");
        }
    }
```

This successfully updated the correct adapter 'Name' data within Windows Registry and the correct adapter name in the Network and Sharing Centre.
However, I get the failed message internally from the code (no exceptions thrown though (have removed exception handling code for readability)) and doing an ipconfig shows that the adpater name has not been updated.

Environment is Windows10 (needs to also work on Windows7), both 64bit architectures, application built as a 32bit application.

Any ideas what is going on? I am at a total loss at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that I have all the information to just do a netsh command:

netsh interface set interface name="" newname=""